# ASP.NET URL routing - Page.GetRouteUrl vs hard coding the URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-routing

Is there any difference between:

```
<asp:Literal ID="lit1" runat="server" />

lit1.Text = "<a href=\"" + Page.GetRouteUrl("view", new { id = "1" }) + "\">View</a>";
```

and:

```
<a href="/view/1">View</a>
```

I use the two ways interchangeably depending on what I'm doing. Is there any risk in hard coding the URL like in the second way?

Comment: You should be fine hard coding the URL. The two methods are essentially the same thing in the end. Just make sure to update your URL if you change your controller actions.

Comment: And, thank you, very much, character limit